# How to Resolve InvalidCastException was unhandled by User code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
GridViewRow row=((GridViewRow )((ImageButton )e.CommandSource ).NamingContainer );
ImageButton imgdelete = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("imgdelete");

string pid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
if (e.CommandName == "Edit"){
    Response.Redirect("PatientRegistration.aspx?pdid=" + pid);
}
if (e.CommandName == "Delete"){
    BL_Property.PatientID = pid;
    BL_Patient.DeletePatient(BL_Property);
    ShowAllPatient();
}
```

I used two Image Buttons for edit and delete I got first page properly when I click for next page I got an error

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled by User code
Error Message :- Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton'
```

Comment: Don't try to cast a `GridView` to an `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code out:

```
GridViewRow row= (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton )e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
mageButton imgdelete = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("imgdelete");
```

Comment: Please avoid posting answers without text explainations. Just few words are better than nothing. No need to write essays either. Take a look at my edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton` in your code line with Parentheses `(` misplaced,

```
GridViewRow row=((GridViewRow )((ImageButton )e.CommandSource ).NamingContainer );
```

Try this,

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)  (((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

Comment: You mean parenthesis.